# Bytes to integer conversion

Tags: c#

I need to convert the byte data to integer:

```
byte[] mode = new byte[3] {50, 53, 53};
```

I tried to convert using `BitConverter.ToInt32(mode, 0)` but got an exception:

> Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.

**Update:** The expected result after conversion is 255.

Comment: What's wrong with this question? why 2 down votes ?

Comment: it's really confusing what you are trying to ask, because it's not really obvious at all what `byte[3]` is supposed to represent.  It's definitely not an integer, though....

Comment: Since you've read MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx) article very carefully before asking this question it is unclear what else do you expect (as this exception is mentioned directly in exceptions section: "startIndex is greater than or equal to the length of value minus 3, and is less than or equal to the length of value minus 1.").

Comment: Biggest issue with the question is that you didn't finish explaining what value you expected... but now that we have the answer I think this is a helpful question to other people who might run into the same situation. In your question try to include a complete code example including your expected output, that might mean trying to create your byte array from the expected result... then you will get a much better response from the community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but `BitConverter.ToInt32` requires 4 bytes of data to work with and you're passing it an array of 3 bytes. Add one more byte and it will work, meaning it will not throw an exception and will do the conversion, but I'm not sure if it will give you want you want.

Example:

```
byte[] mode = new byte[4] {50, 53, 53, 00};
var result = BitConverter.ToInt32(mode, 0); //Result will be 3487026
```

**EDIT** Apparently this array represents text, not an integer. To convert it, you need to know the encoding used. If it is guaranteed to have only numbers, then you can use ASCII:

```
byte[] mode = new byte[3]{50, 53, 53};
string result = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(mode); //Result will be 255
```

Now, if you want to convert it to an integer, then it is simple. Use any conversion method like `int.Parse()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`.

Comment: 255 is the expected value

Comment: 255 is a single byte though? so this should be 255: {255,0,0,0}

Comment: Good pickup @RacilHilan I didn't know op meant "255"

Comment: @RacilHilan please edit question so future visitors can makes sense of your answer.

Comment: @RacilHilan I agree that answer is clear. That's why I suggested to edit question...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Done. Does it look better now?